# PNP site provisioning: how to remove top link bar and site title completely?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision

I would like to remove the top link bar and the page title and gain the space occupied by them.
I can hide them by adding this to the template:

```
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
.ms-displayInline.ms-core-navigation, .ms-core-pageTitle{
  display:none;
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
```

But now there's a big white space, so I didn't really earn anything. How can I collapse these elements?